# Django: prepare query but don't execute it

Tags: django

I am trying to make some efficient queries with Django in the following loop:

```
for division in divisions:
  playoffs = league.playoff_set.filter(division=division, double_elimination=True)
```

I thought maybe filtering `playoffs` before the loop by selecting only those with `double_elimination=True` would enhance it:

```
playoffs = league.playoff_set.filter(double_elimination=True)
for division in divisions:
  division_playoffs = playoffs.filter(division=division)
```

But now I am concerned that this is firing the query from `playoffs` in every run at the loop instead of filtering on the previously retrieved result.

Is it working as expected or as I am fearing? Should I use `Q` instead to build these better-performing queries?

Comment: Django querysets are lazy, they arent executed until you need the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). That means that the queryset isn't evaluated when you do

```
playoffs = league.playoff_set.filter(double_elimination=True)
```

It isn't even evaluated when you filter the queryset again in the loop.

```
division_playoffs = playoffs.filter(division=division)
```

[The queryset will only be evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) when you access its contents (either in the view or in the template).

```
playoffs = league.playoff_set.filter(double_elimination=True)
for division in divisions:
    division_playoffs = playoffs.filter(division=division)
    for playoff in division_playoffs:  # looping through queryset causes it to be evaluated
        print(playoff)
```

Therefore, both versions of your code will work the same. you should choose the one that you find to be clearer.

Comment: So even if I stayed with the original approach (when the query was  `playoffs = league.playoff_set.filter(division=division, double_elimination=True)` in every loop) it would be as efficient?

Comment: You can use something like the Django debug toolbar to look at the resulting SQL queries. As I said, both versions of your code will work the same.

Comment: You can view SQL queries that have been run, might help you understand whats happning under the hood. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074212/how-to-show-the-sql-django-is-running

If there is a significant number of divisions, but not a overwhelming number of playoffs, it may be best just to query `league.playoff_set.filter(double_elimination=True)` and then group the results in python. eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071888/python-group-list-items-in-a-dict