# Iterate over list of dict and group item by key

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have a list of dicts:

```
my_list = [
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-14', 'price': 20.0},
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-15', 'price': 22.0},
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-16', 'price': 30.0},
    {'name': 'BBB', 'date': '2018-05-14', 'price': 15.0},
    {'name': 'BBB', 'date': '2018-05-15', 'price': 32.0}
    ]
```

My question is how can I iterate over that list to produce a list in this format?

```
parsed_list = [
    {'name': 'AAA', 'data': [['2018-05-14', 20.0], ['2018-05-15', 22.0], ['2018-05-16', 30.0]]},
    {'name': 'BBB', 'data': [['2018-05-14', 15.0], ['2018-05-15', 32.0]]}
    ]
```

I tried approach described in this question: [Python: group list items in a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071888/python-group-list-items-in-a-dict)
but I need a different output format and I can't figure out what I need to change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way may be to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-14', 'price': 20.0},
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-15', 'price': 22.0},
    {'name': 'AAA', 'date': '2018-05-16', 'price': 30.0},
    {'name': 'BBB', 'date': '2018-05-14', 'price': 15.0},
    {'name': 'BBB', 'date': '2018-05-15', 'price': 32.0}
    ]

tmp = defaultdict(list)

for item in my_list:
    tmp[item['name']].append([item['date'],item['price']])
    
parsed_list = [{'name':k, 'data':v} for k,v in tmp.items()]
print(parsed_list)
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'AAA', 'data': [['2018-05-14', 20.0], 
                          ['2018-05-15', 22.0], ['2018-05-16', 30.0]]}, 
 {'name': 'BBB', 'data': [['2018-05-14', 15.0], ['2018-05-15', 32.0]]}]
```

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
print([{"name": key, "data": [(g['date'], g['price']) for g in group]} 
       for key, group in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x['name'])])
#[{'name': 'AAA', 'data': [('2018-05-14', 20.0), ('2018-05-15', 22.0), ('2018-05-16', 30.0)]},
# {'name': 'BBB', 'data': [('2018-05-14', 15.0), ('2018-05-15', 32.0)]}]
```

The first argument to `groupby` is an iterable, in this case `my_list`.

The second argument is a function that defines how to create the groups, in this case you extract the key `name`.

**Note**: this will group *consecutive* items with the same `name`, so it assumes that `my_list` is already sorted with respect to name. If not you can sort first using:

```
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x['name'])
```

Then we can iterate over all the `(key, group)` pairs from the output of `groupby()` and do a list comprehension.

Inside the list comprehension, we do a dict comprehension `{"name": key, "data": [(g['date'], g['price']) for g in group]}` to build a dictionary of the form `{'name': key, 'data': [[date,price]]}` for each `name`.