# Get following dict structure in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

May sounds like a noobie question. I have the following resultant from MongoDB : 
[Part1]

```
  {
        "hour" : 7,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 2,
        "readableDate" : "2019-02-20",
        "totalCount" : 4.0
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "hour" : 5,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 2,
        "readableDate" : "2019-02-20",
        "totalCount" : 3.0
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "hour" : 2,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 2,
        "readableDate" : "2019-02-20",
        "totalCount" : 5.0
    }

    /* 4 */
    {
        "hour" : 11,
        "dayOfWeek" : 3,
        "month" : 2,
        "readableDate" : "2019-02-19",
        "totalCount" : 7.0
    }

    /* 5 */
    {
        "hour" : 4,
        "dayOfWeek" : 5,
        "month" : 1,
        "readableDate" : "2019-01-17",
        "totalCount" : 6.0
    }

    /* 6 */
    {
        "hour" : 1,
        "dayOfWeek" : 5,
        "month" : 1,
        "readableDate" : "2019-01-17",
        "totalCount" : 4.0
    }

    /* 7 */
    {
        "hour" : 15,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 1,
        "readableDate" : "2019-01-16",
        "totalCount" : 3.0
    }

    /* 8 */
    {
        "hour" : 10,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 1,
        "readableDate" : "2019-01-16",
        "totalCount" : 11.0
    }

    /* 9 */
    {
        "hour" : 9,
        "dayOfWeek" : 4,
        "month" : 1,
        "readableDate" : "2019-01-16",
        "totalCount" : 6.0
    }
```

## Edit :

Now considering that 20th February was Wednesday and 19th February was Tuesday. I want to convert the following resultant set into a dict with following format : 
[PART 2]

```
  {
        Wednesday: {
                    0: 15,
                    1: 55,
                    2: 15,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    23: 15
                },
        Tuesday:{
                    0: 15,
                    1: 55,
                    2: 15,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    23: 15
        }
```

Values in the above structure are values of the 'hour' key taken from Part 1 which are shown as reference in Part-2

One of the things I tried is whenever I get the output from the aggregation in PyMongo : 
I dump the same creating a list :

```
total_item_list = []
for doc in collection_from_database.aggregate(pipe_):
    total_item_list.append(doc)

for element in total_item_list:
    if element['dayOfWeek'] == 1:
        final_structure_output[element['hour']] = element['totalCount']
```

The problem with this approach is that I am still not getting the correct resultant dict as I wanted. And secondly, iterating it over for entire set seems unoptimized way to me.

Hope I am clear with my question. TIA

Comment: 0:00 AM: 15 what is key and value? Where do you get 15 and 55 from?

Comment: This is very similar to a lot of previous questions, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071888/python-group-list-items-in-a-dict

Comment: @user8426627updated my question.